# "is it create" or "is it to create"

Tags: grammar

In the sentence:

"This app have two basic functions, one is it create posts and the other is it create photo galleries."

I'm not sure about the right form to writte it. Another option:

"This app have two basic functions, one is it to create posts and the other is it to create photo galleries."

Maybe one of them is it better expressed than the other?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello @Christianjs19, both sentences are incorrect grammatically as you're talking about a single app having multiple functions. Try "This app **has** two basic functions, one is **to create** posts and the other is **to create** photo galleries."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is "to create" (option 2). Use "has" (singular) instead of "have" (plural), as "app" is singular. Also, I would use a colon after "functions" or a period. A comma is just a splice of what is really two sentences.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I wanted to know.. Thank You @R. Daniel!

Comment: Yes, the comma splice is not good in this instance. The _it_'s?